# Swift: Cannot handle the date function properly while subtracting the Date:

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I am trying to set the minimum date to 1987 from present date. I have successfully implemented this but i cannot figure out why the Past months from present months are fields are disable.

Like Todays current month is August then if i select 1987 as the year then Months before August are disabled.I cannot figure out why is this happening?

This is my code to calculate max and min dates:

```
    let currentDate: NSDate = NSDate()

    let calendar: NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
    // let calendar: NSCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

    let components: NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents()
    components.calendar = calendar

    components.year = -30
    components.day = -0
    components.month = -0
    let minDate: NSDate = calendar.dateByAddingComponents(components, toDate: currentDate, options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))!

    components.year = -0
    components.day = -0
    components.month = -0
    let maxDate: NSDate = calendar.dateByAddingComponents(components, toDate: currentDate, options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))!


    self.datePicker.datePicker.maximumDate = maxDate
    self.datePicker.datePicker.minimumDate = minDate


    print("minDate is the: \(minDate)")
    print("maxDate is the: \(maxDate)")
```

It is working fine for the dates after 1987.I want to enable all the months and days even for 1987

Comment: As Vandian said in his answer and comments, at this point you should not be supporting Swift 2 code, much less writing new code in Swift 2. You should be using Swift 3. If you're dealing with an old app in Swift 2, it's time to convert it to Swift 3. The current version of Xcode has an automatic upgrade facility that does most of the work for you, but that won't be available forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to subtract 30 years from today and get the beginning of the year (January 1st) use

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
var components = calendar.dateComponents([.year], from: Date())
components.year! -= 30
let minDate = calendar.date(from: components)!
```

It extracts only the `year` component from the current date and subtracts 30. As `month` and `day` are not specified a value of 1 is considered respectively.

The code is written in Swift 3, it's highly recommended to update. Swift 4 is coming up.

Comment: can you provide this answer for swift 2 please

Comment: I'm afraid I can't because I don't use Swift 2 anymore for a long time. Please look up the two methods in the documentation, `Calendar` is `NSCalendar` and `DateComponents` is `NSDateComponents` in Swift 2.

Comment: let calendar1 = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let date0 = NSDate()
        let unitFlags: NSCalendarUnit = [.Year]
        let components0 = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(unitFlags, fromDate: date0)
        components0.year = -30
        
        let mindate = calendar1.dateFromComponents(components0) but still does have same problem

Comment: Try additionally `components0.month = 1` and `components0.day = 1` before the line `let mindate...` and it's `components0.year -= 30`

Comment: Still january to July and  and days 1 t0 4 are disabled

Comment: What date do you get when you print `minDate`? Wait, pass `let unitFlags: NSCalendarUnit = [.Year, .Month, .Day]` then set  month and day to 1

Comment: min date is printed as 1987-08-05 17:33:25 +0000

Comment: Did you try to extract year, **month and day** and then set month and day to 1?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151153/discussion-between-jenny-sam-and-vadian).

Answer (score 2):

What it's doing makes perfect sense. If you build a date that's August 5, 1987, and install it as the minimum date for a date picker, you're telling the date picker that the user should not be able to select a date earlier than that. If the user selects the year 1987, then a month earlier than August is less than the specified minimum date. It won't let the user pick a date before August 5, 1987.

### Edit

If you want to allow any date in 1987, you should make the minimum date in the date picker Jan 1 1987. You could do that with date components by setting the month and day both to 1.

Comment: How can i enable those months?

Comment: I need to set only year to 1987 and remain other as it is.Is it possible?